# Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK React Native Push notification integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, react-native

I'm a newbie to SalesForce. I am trying to integrate this package https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk to my React Native app for push notifications. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to register the device to the Marketing Cloud via a React Native form?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please let me know how did receive the notification info in App.js when user clicks the notification on Android?

Comment: Hi @rkaartikeyan I used [react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications) package for reading remote notifications.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried the wix react-native-notifications, same problem, it's working fine for iOS, I am able to receive the push notification from SFMC Mobile Push with `Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened()` in iPhone, but for android it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

No form needed. Initialize the SDK and the device will automatically be registered.

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed the SDK and the device were registered but there's no contact key.

Comment: Then you didn't set one ;)

Comment: How we can set the contact key, also is there any example where I can integrate SFMC react-native SDK in my react-native app? Or any step by step approach, I already followed - https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk, but its keep failing Android emulator build

Comment: Set contact key is literally on the page you linked.